# Cross tabulation - Frequency Table in SAS

Tags: sql, sql-server, sas, sas-macro, proc

The dataset is:

```
data sample;
input FY TC;
datalines;
2013 1
2014 5
2013 6
2015 7
2016 1
2015 5
2016 2
2014 2
2013 7
2014 4
2017 5
2018 1
2018 6
2015 4
2014 2
2015 4
;
```

Output desired:

```
    FY  tc1 tc2 tc3 tc4 tc5 tc6 tc7
2013    1   0   0   0   0   1   1
2014    0   2   0   1   1   0   0
2015    0   0   0   2   1   0   1
2016    1   1   0   0   0   0   0
2017    0   0   0   0   1   0   0
2018    1   0   0   0   0   1   0
```

The important point in the above output is that there is no data point for TC=3 but I want it in my output dataset, which I need later for calculation in another step. Again this TC=3 data unavailability is just for depiction only and for one particular category (eg. commercial real estate). For other categories, I might have data points missing for TC=4 (e.g. for residential real estate) or so on. So **I need a cross table where I can have frequency columns for each from TC=1 to TC=7 irrespective of the fact whether any data point is available for TC=1 to TC=7 or not.**

I am well aware of PROC REPORT but it is not creating tables for TC=3. I think it can be done using PROC SQL. Please help me here. I prefer PROC SQL, PROC REPORT as their output can be used easily in a later step.

Not preferred: PROC TABULATE, PROC FREQ

Comment: Weird restriction when proc tabulate and freq both deal with this quite well, using preloadfmt or the sparse option.

Comment: @Reeza they don't take use those values that don't exist in the dataset. In my dataset no Fy has tc=3 but i need it in my output

Comment: @DaleK I have removed the images

Comment: @VaibhavKabdwal yes they very much can with the SPARSE or the PRELOADFMT options.

Comment: @Reeza Why add unnecessary complexity? Look at the PROC SQL solution, I posed below

Comment: Try scaling your solution to 25 values, then 100 or 1000.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a format and the [`preloadfmt`](https://documentation.sas.com/doc/en/pgmsascdc/9.4_3.5/proc/n1dz7jdasx5t56n1rmlx346dyk6n.htm#p1a7hmyohbzsu7n14ccdxvhhx2nc) with `completerows` or `completecols` to get what you're looking for.  Below is the simple version of this, you probably need `completecols` with an `across` variable for yours - can provide that if you provide actual code to produce your table.

```
proc format;
 value age
 9="Nine"
 10="Ten"
 11="Eleven"
 12="Twelve"
 13="Thirteen"
 14="Fourteen"
 15="Fifteen"
 16="Sixteen"
 17="Seventeen"
 ;;;;
run;
 
proc report data=sashelp.class completerows;
column age age=count;
format age age.;
define age/preloadfmt group order=internal;
define count/computed n;
run;
```

Answer (score 0):

I posted this question on the SAS community as well. I am copying some top answers from there.

Getting desired using PROC REPORT:

```
data intermediate;
    set sample end=eof;
    weight=1;
    output;
    if eof then do;
        tc=3;
        weight=0;
        output;
    end;
run;
options missing=0;
proc report data=intermediate;
    columns fy tc,weight;
    define fy/group;
    define tc/across;
    define weight/sum ' ';
    rbreak after/summarize;
run;
```

Credits: Paige Miller (SAS Community)

Getting desired using PROC TABULATE:

```
proc format;
    value yrfmt
    2013=2013
    2014=2014
    2015=2015
    2016=2016
    2017=2017
    ;
    
    value tcfmt
    1=1
    2=2
    3=3
    4=4
    5=5
    6=6
    7=7
    ;
run;

proc tabulate data=sample out=counts;
    class FY tc / preloadfmt;
    format tc tcfmt. fy yrfmt.;
    table FY*tc / printmiss;
run;

proc sort data=counts;
    by fy;
run;

proc transpose data=counts out=counts_t (drop=_name_) prefix=tc;
    by fy;
    var N;
    id tc;
run;
```

Credits: Irackley (SAS Community)

Answer (score 0):

The top answer from SAS Community:

```
proc sql;
    select FY, 
    sum(TC=1) as tc1,
    sum(TC=2) as tc2,
    sum(TC=3) as tc3,
    sum(TC=4) as tc4,
    sum(TC=5) as tc5,
    sum(TC=6) as tc6,
    sum(TC=7) as tc7
        from sample
        group by FY;
quit;
```

**Credits:** **Irackley (SAS Community)**